# Maximum number of points in a CLR chart series

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, c++-cli, clr, charts

I am just starting out in c++ and have found a CLR chart control through visual studio.

Project->Add New Item->User Control (Under UI)->Chart (Under Data)

I know in Excel these types of charts are limited to 32,000 points. I am wondering if I create my own native app am I still going to be restrcited by this limitation? Is this limitation enforced by Excel or the Chart itself?

Comment: Is there a screen on earth that can display 32,000 points so the human eye can see them all?

Comment: @benPearce I'm still trying to figure out how to do that

Comment: @Steve its not so much the point they can be seen, but calculated.

Comment: @benPearce - The chart control doesn't calculate anything.  You give it data and it displays it.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @Steve: For an interactive chart that allows pan and zoom (Excel doesn't), 32000 points would be a ridiculously low limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing who makes the particular chart control you're asking about, no one can tell you what its limits are.  I don't think there's any Chart control that comes with Visual Studio, most likely you're seeing an ActiveX control installed by some other piece of software on your computer.